# Express js why use a Router?

Tags: node.js, express

Why would I do:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', ...)
```

instead of

```
app.get('/', ...);
```

The two will give me the same result. What's the point of instantiating a router if app is already a router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's useful if you're writing a very complex app. For example, you might have a tree like this:

```
routes
    user.js
    post.js
server.js
```

In both `user.js` and `post.js`, you would create a `Router` object and export it. You can attach all the routes for the user to that router - say `/user/new`, `/user/edit`, and `/user/1`, and `/post/new`, `/post/edit`, and `/post/1`.

In `server.js`, you would `require` each of your routes and attach their routers via `app.use`:

```
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/post', post);
```

All requests to `/user` will then be sent to the user router, and all requests to `/post` will be sent to the post router. Then, you can register routes like:

```
router.get('/new', function(req, res) { });
```

And it will automatically be mapped to `/user/new` or `/post/new`. This is useful because it helps organize your app, and it forces you to segregate one section of your application into one file (separation of concerns and all that). It's a useful part of express that isn't very well advertised.

Answer (score 1):

[Revisiting the router middleware](http://www.packtpub.com/article/understanding-express-routes)

> The router middleware is very special middleware. While other Express
>   middlewares are inherited from Connect, router is implemented by
>   Express itself. This middleware is solely responsible for empowering
>   Express with Sinatra-like routes.
>   The router middleware is a middleware system of its own. The route
>   definitions form the middlewares in this stack. Meaning, a matching
>   route can respond with an HTTP response and end the request flow, or
>   pass on the request to the next middleware in line.

and then

> To ensure predictability and stability, we should explicitly add
>   router to the middleware stack

```
app.use(app.router);
```